# How to set the SPI channel and read the measured values

Tags: stm32, sensor, spi, c

I want to use the SPI of an STM32 to read several sensor measurements

How can I set up a channel?

I'm looking for it and using it, but I can't see it coming out properly.

They say that you can use something like `HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive` for the sensor measurement, but I'm not sure about this, and I need to know how to set up a channel first

SPI [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads8688.pdf).

I made it by referring to the [STM32 project here](https://github.com/obatsis/ADS8688-STM32), but seeing that all the measurements are repeated, I don't know if I did it wrong or if it doesn't fit me.

Even if the sensor and the type of value (voltage, temperature, etc.) you measure are different, isn't it the same to read the measurements?

`SPI_ADS_Init(&ads, &hspi2, GPIOB, 9);` I did it like this when I initialized it. There's nothing else besides changing the name of the variable.

I did the following when I asked for the price:

```c
SPI_ADS_Init(&ads, &hspi2, GPIOB, 9);

for(;;) {
    SPI_Read_All_Raw(&ads, ads_data);
}
```

```c
HAL_StatusTypeDef SPI_Read_All_Raw(SPI_ADS *ads, uint16_t *data) {
    HAL_StatusTypeDef ret;
    uint8_t ads_raw[2];
    for(int i=0; i < CHNS_NUM_READ; i++) {
        ret = SPI_Cmd_Write(ads, SPI_CONT, ads_raw);
        data[i] = (int)((uint16_t)(ads_raw[1]<<8 | ads_raw[0]) >> 4);

        printf("%04X\n\r", data[i]);
    }
    return ret;
}

uint8_t SPI_ADS_Init(SPI_ADS *ads, SPI_HandleTypeDef *spiHandle, GPIO_TypeDef *csPinBank, uint16_t csPin) {
    /* Store interface parameters in struct */
    ads->spiHandle      = spiHandle;
    ads->csPinBank  = csPinBank;
    ads->csPin      = csPin;

    uint8_t ads_data[2] = {0};
    uint8_t state = 0;

    // reset all registers to default
    state += SPI_Cmd_Write(ads, SPI_RST, ads_data);
    HAL_Delay(100);

    // send a no_op message to the ADS to enter IDLE mode
    state += SPI_Cmd_Write(ads, SPI_CONT, ads_data);
    HAL_Delay(10);

    // enable auto transmit for all inputs(datasheet page 54) or as many as you want
    // if you want only some of the inputs enabled, make sure to power down the unused ones
    ads_data[0] = 0xff;
    state += SPI_Prog_Write(ads, SPI_AUTO_SEQ_EN, ads_data);
    HAL_Delay(10);


    // set the desired features such as device id (if multiple devices are used), alarm enable/disable and output format
    ads_data[0] = 0x00; // here i chose id = 0, alarm = disabled and SDO_format = 3 (datasheet page 56)
    state += SPI_Prog_Write(ads, SPI_FEATURE_SELECT, ads_data);
    HAL_Delay(10);

    ads_data[0] = 0x06;
    state += SPI_Prog_Write(ads, SPI_CHN_RANGE_0, ads_data);
    HAL_Delay(10);

    ads_data[0] = 0x06;
    state += SPI_Prog_Write(ads, SPI_CHN_RANGE_1, ads_data);
    HAL_Delay(10);

    ads_data[0] = 0x05;
    state += SPI_Prog_Write(ads, SPI_CHN_RANGE_2, ads_data);
    HAL_Delay(10);

    ads_data[0] = 0x05;
    state += SPI_Prog_Write(ads, SPI_CHN_RANGE_3, ads_data);
    HAL_Delay(10);

    ads_data[0] = 0x05;
    state += SPI_Prog_Write(ads, SPI_CHN_RANGE_4, ads_data);
    HAL_Delay(10);

    ads_data[0] = 0x05;
    state += SPI_Prog_Write(ads, SPI_CHN_RANGE_5, ads_data);
    HAL_Delay(10);

    ads_data[0] = 0x06;
    state += SPI_Prog_Write(ads, SPI_CHN_RANGE_6, ads_data);
    HAL_Delay(10);

    ads_data[0] = 0x06;
    state += SPI_Prog_Write(ads, SPI_CHN_RANGE_7, ads_data);
    HAL_Delay(10);

    // start the auto transmission by entering the appropriate state
    state += SPI_Cmd_Write(ads, SPI_AUTO_RST, ads_data);

    return state;
}
```

What I want to know is the source code for setting up the SPI channel.

Everyone wants me to look at the datasheet, but I don't know how to source it.

Measured value to be output:

[image]

Comment: `data[i] = (int)((uint16_t)(ads_raw[1]<<8 | ads_raw[0]) >> 4);` is doing some completely senseless casts. This should have been written as `data[i] = (uint16_t) (((uint32_t)ads_raw[1]<<8 | (uint32_t)ads_raw[0]) >> 4);` Or better yet do it in several lines since all those parenthesis makes it hard to read.

Comment: If you don't know how to use the STM32 HSAL libraries to configure the MCU's peripherals, then you'll probably need to download & use something like the STM32CubeMX application which writes the code for you after you make your selections with checkboxes & drop-down lists.

Comment: What is connected to your analog inputs? How do you decide that the readings are wrong?

Comment: Remove the >>4 in the SPI_Read_All_Raw() function. It is a bug in the demo library.

Comment: The connected sensors include temperature sensors, carbon dioxide sensors, etc However, you can't say that you're getting the measurements because you're repeating 2 or 3 values